# Alternative to for loop to iterate through dataframe sequentially

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I've a very large dataframe which is for a battery discharge schedule, for every second of the year.

The basic series of events is

- Event Occurs
- Battery Discharges
- Stops discharging
- X seconds after discharging stops, start recharge
- Stop charging when battery fully charged

The dataframe looks like this... (forgive my poor formatting)

```
Index | Freq | Case | Battery OP | Power Required | Battery Energy | SOC | Response timer | Charge Power |

01/01/2016 | 49.5862 | C | Discharging | 300.512 | 1500 | 99.85 | 3 | 0 |

01/01/2016 | 49.5862 | C | Charging    | 0       | 1500 | 99.85 | 3 | 1500 |
```

I'm currently using a for loop and some if/elseif statements to iterate through each row, checking whether battery needs to be charged or not.

I think its very inefficient though. I might be running out of memory or else its taking days to complete.

I left it running over the weekend and it still hadn't finished

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I'm not aware. The issue is it has to be sequential. State of charge or battery Energy needs to be calculated for each second based on the power in or out of the battery and the previous SOC%/Energy.

Reproducible code here (tried to cut it down as much as I could)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


Battery_W = 1000
Battery_Wh = 1000/ 3
starting_SOC = 0.75
charge_delay = 5
charging = False

year_test = pd.DataFrame(data = [50.00,50.00,49.99,49.98,49.87,49.76,49.65,49.25,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,49.99,49.78,49.67,49.46,49.25,49.25,50.00,50.00,50.00,49.95,49.65,49.45,49.65,49.55,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,49.95,49.65,49.45,49.65,49.55,49.99,49.68,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00],index = range(0,50),columns= ['Freq'])


case_conditions = [
    (year_test['Freq'] <= 49.75 ),                                 
    (year_test['Freq'] > 49.75 )   
    ]
choices = ['C', 'B']
year_test['Case'] = np.select(case_conditions, choices, default='No Case')

"Battery Operation mode"
op_conditions = [
        (year_test['Case'] == 'C'),
        (year_test['Case'] == 'B')
]
#%%
op_choices = ['Discharging','Idle']
year_test['Battery OP']= np.select(op_conditions, op_choices, default = 'No OP Mode')

"Calculate power output required"

power_conditions = [
        (year_test['Case'] == 'B'),
        (year_test['Case'] == 'C')
]

power_choices = [1000,0]
year_test['Power Required']= np.select(power_conditions, power_choices, default = 0)

year_test['Battery Energy'] = 0.0
year_test['SOC%'] = 0

"Response Timer"
year_test['Response timer'] = year_test.groupby('Battery OP').cumcount()
year_test['Response timer'][year_test['Battery OP'] == 'Idle' ] = 0

year_test['Charge Power'] = 0.00


year_test['Battery Energy'] = 0.0
year_test['Battery Energy'].iloc[0] = Battery_Wh * starting_SOC 
year_test['Battery Energy'].iloc[0:charge_delay] = Battery_Wh * starting_SOC


for j in range(charge_delay, len(year_test)):
    if year_test.iloc[j-(charge_delay) ,3]  > 0 and year_test.iloc[j - ((charge_delay) -1), 3] == 0 :
        "charge at max rate"
        year_test.iloc[j,7] = Battery_W
        year_test.iloc[j,2] = "Charging"
        charging = True

    elif charging == True and year_test.iloc[j-1,4] < starting_SOC * Battery_Wh:
        "check if battery charged"
        year_test.iloc[j,7] = Battery_W
        year_test.iloc[j,2] = "Charging"

    elif year_test.iloc[j-1,4] >= starting_SOC * Battery_Wh or charging == False:
        charging = False
        year_test.iloc[j,7] = 0.0

    "New Battery Energy"    
    year_test.iloc[j,4] = year_test.iloc[(j-1),4] - ((year_test.iloc[j,3])/60/60) + ((year_test.iloc[j,7])/60/60)
    if year_test.iloc[j,4] > Battery_Wh :
        year_test.iloc[j,4] = Battery_Wh

"Calculate battery SOC% for empty"

year_test['SOC%'] = year_test['Battery Energy'] / Battery_Wh * 100
```

Comment: Could you give an example dataframe that is reduced to the relevant fields and an expected output? Its rather hard to read your code.

Comment: I agree with Tillmann, it would be easy to help you if you could provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok , I'll try add one now

Comment: I think you might be missing the boolean `charging=True` at the beginning of the code...anyways the problem is clearly appending new columns after you create the first column 'Freq'. You have 2 options: Get 'Freq' and  'Case' columns from dictionary manipulations or use `df.itertuples()`...Let me try to wrap that in a quick code...

Comment: A bit unclear from your code - what data do you have and what data are you trying to generate? Can you give an example input dataframe and an example output, and what you expect the rules to be for your outputs?

Comment: My input data is a load of .csv files with datetime and frequency value, for every second of the year. I have the datetime set as the index in the df. For output I'd like a dataframe with columns datetime,Power in/out and SOC%.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, since you are running out of memory, is to use the apply method of panda data-frame. This methodology is called vectorization.

An example is as follows `df.apply(numpy.sqrt, axis=1)`

You can look at the documentation for more details: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply

Comment: Do you know if .apply will work when the current row values depend on previous rows

Comment: I'm not sure if it does that but the good thing about .apply is that fact that it takes a function. So if you need values from your previous row you can write it into your function that .apply will call. I hope that's clear enough?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try .apply with shift and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might possibly re-write your code. I am simply reducing the initial 7 columns into a dictionary and then using `pd.DataFrame()` to convert them into a Proper DataFrame. Then I simply apply your `if...elif` statements while iterating through the constructed DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


Battery_W = 1000
Battery_Wh = 1000/ 3
starting_SOC = 0.75
charge_delay = 5
charging = True

#initialize test Dictionary 
test = {}

#add your test elements as a tuple
data = (50.00,50.00,49.99,49.98,49.87,49.76,49.65,49.25,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,49.99,49.78,49.67,49.46,49.25,49.25,50.00,50.00,50.00,49.95,49.65,49.45,49.65,49.55,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,49.95,49.65,49.45,49.65,49.55,49.99,49.68,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00,50.00)
index = 0
#"Battery Operation mode" is not calculated seperately now
#"Calculate power output required" is not calculated seperately now
for d in data:
    if d <= 49.75:
    test[index] = {'Freq': d,
                   'Case': 'C',
                   'Battery_OP':'Discharging',
                   'Power_Required':0,
                   'Battery_Energy':0.0,
                   'SOC':0,
                   'Charge_Power' :0.0
                   }
    elif d > 49.75:
        test[index] = {'Freq': d,
                   'Case': 'B',
                   'Battery_OP': 'Idle',
                   'Power_Required': 1000,
                   'Battery_Energy': 0.0,
                   'SOC': 0,
                   'Charge_Power': 0.0}
   index +=1
#This is how I convert the dictionary into a df for the first-time
year_test = pd.DataFrame(test.values())

year_test['Response_timer'] = year_test.groupby('Battery_OP').cumcount()
year_test['Response_timer'][year_test['Battery_OP'] == 'Idle'] = 0

year_test['ChargePower'] = 0.00
year_test['BatteryEnergy'] = 0.0
year_test['BatteryEnergy'].iloc[0:charge_delay] = Battery_Wh * starting_SOC

j = charge_delay
#instead of using the range(), try to manipulate it using `itertuples()`
#This is most probably where you are losing your time..
for row in year_test.itertuples():
    if row.Index <5:
        continue
    if year_test.iloc[j-charge_delay, 3]  > 0 and year_test.iloc[j - ((charge_delay) -1), 3] == 0 :
        "charge at max rate"
        year_test.iloc[j,7] = Battery_W
        year_test.iloc[j,2] = "Charging"
        charging = True

    elif charging == True and year_test.iloc[j-1,4] < starting_SOC * Battery_Wh:
        "check if battery charged"
        year_test.iloc[j,7] = Battery_W
        year_test.iloc[j,2] = "Charging"

    elif year_test.iloc[j-1,4] >= starting_SOC * Battery_Wh or charging == False:
        charging = False
        year_test.iloc[j,7] = 0.0

    "New Battery Energy"
    year_test.iloc[j,4] = year_test.iloc[(j-1),4] - ((year_test.iloc[j,3])/60/60) + ((year_test.iloc[j,7])/60/60)
    if year_test.iloc[j,4] > Battery_Wh :
        year_test.iloc[j,4] = Battery_Wh

"Calculate battery SOC% for empty"
year_test['SOC'] = year_test['BatteryEnergy'] / Battery_Wh * 100
```

Comment: Thanks , I'll give this a shot and see

Comment: I tried this method, and I'm printing the progress of the loop about every 1000 rows but at current rate I'm still looking at 27 hours per month of data :(

Comment: Instead of loading the dictionary to a normal dataframe like in `pd.dataFrame(test.values())`, try adding it to a feather, parquet or try Apache Arrow for faster data access and analysis..[This](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/pandas-and-apache-arrow/) might help in getting started...